# $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$ are uncountable

Tags: real-analysis

To prove the un-countability of $(a,b)$, Pugh tries to establish a bijection between $(a,b)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ in this way-

> There are bijections from $(a,b)$ onto $(-1,1)$ onto the uni semi-circle onto $\mathbb{R}$ as shown in the figure.(unfortunately, I do not know how to attach the figure)

Can  anyone please help me establish this fact by his hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a linear map that takes $a$ to $-1$ and $b$ to $1$. Then you can identify $(-1,1)$ with a portion of the $x$-axis, and take $(x,0)$ to $(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})$. Then to each point on the semi-circle you can associate an angle strictly between $0$ and $\pi$, and associate to each angle its cotangent.

Comment: In particular , we can use the map $f(x)=\frac{2x-a-b}{b-a}$ to establish (a,b)~(-1,1).Right?

Comment: @Worker: That's right.